# Need help rotating faces as seen in image

Tags: modeling, faces, topology

I've been trying to find a solution in this forum and online, but unfortunately, I haven't come across a suitable answer. I'm hoping that someone here can assist me with my query.

I'm trying to figure out how to rotate faces as seen in the image. If anyone has experience or knowledge in this area, I'd greatly appreciate your guidance.

Thank you in advance[image]

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are asking. What faces do you want to rotate and in which direction? Please provide an image  with annotations showing what you want to achieve.

Comment: @JohnEason: also i am not totally sure, but i think he doesn't want to rotate but "kind of" triangulate the faces so that this pattern will be created.

Comment: @Chris That's why I asked for clarification! :^)

Comment: No I don't want to triangulate my faces. I want my quads to be rotated 45 degrees as seen in the images I've attached! :)

Comment: Well they won't be quads if you want to do that! (5 vertices instead of 4.) Subdivide the outer edges and move the centre verts outwards. At the corners you can join the verts across the quad, delete the corner one and then extrude the corner edge.

Comment: @JohnEason 5 vertices instead of 4? Where do you get the fifth vertex from? Or are you counting the intersections of the grid floor in? But anyway, N03: this is not a simple rotation of squares - or at least not if they were assembled in a grid beforehand - because they are in a different order now. But you are not even providing any screenshot or detailed information how your original mesh looks or how it is built so that we can draw any conclusions of what might be necessary to get from the initial state to this.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann : I assume that the poster of the question wants to produce the shape that he's shown in his image which looks as if it started as a simple plane subdivided by loop cuts. The outer edges of all the quads would have to be subdivide and the verts produced moved to create the shapes shown in the image. I still don't understand the "quads rotated 45 degrees" statement though which is why I requested an annotated image.

Comment: @JohnEason Well, the edges of the faces are the cyan lines, the black lines are just the world grid or something like that... so they are quads, and they are rotated by 45° instead of having their edges aligned horizontally and vertically. The problem is (what the poster somehow doesn't know/realize?), if you have a subdivided plane and just would go and rotate each face by 45°, you will never get the desired result. But that's why I want clarification: there is no information if it is really a subdivided plane or any other mesh which should be transformed...

Comment: Actually I didn't realise there **were** any cyan lines with the small size of the image and couldn't even see the diagonal faces until I enlarged the view considerably! I'm not going to comment any further without more details!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just rotate a subdivided grid, select a rectangle and remove the excess?

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is want I wanted.